# Populating a ref in Forms in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, ref

I'm finding using refs in forms very useful when creating a new form and obtaining the values when I submit it. However, is there a way to add a value to a preexisting form using ref?

```
<input className="form-control" ref={email => (this.email = email)} placeholder="Email" />
```

I want to use the same form/component for the "create/edit" but I'm not sure how I would add a preexisting value to a ref.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an uncontrolled input you can use `defaultValue` prop to set initial value, read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) for more info. Note that for checkboxes and radio buttons you should use `defaultChecked` prop instead.

Another option is to write [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and set/change `value` manually.